# Importxml google spreadsheet parsing formula error

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, xml-parsing

I tried to use this formula

```
=ImportXML("http://www.google.com/search?q=philadelphia seo company&num=100", "//h3[@class='r']/a/@href")
```

from  http://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/importxml-cookbook/

and I get an formula error , you need to enable something in google spreadsheet before using this formula?

Comment: Please provide the error so we could better assist you.

Comment: Also, if your locale uses a comma for a decimal separator, you will need to use a semi-colon rather than a comma in your formula.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the part of the search query where "q=philadelphia seo company" meaning all the spaces should be converted to "%20".

end result should look like this:

`=ImportXML("http://www.google.com/search?q=philadelphia%20seo%20company&num=100", "//h3[@class='r']/a/@href")`

also - i use importxml all the time and with google search results, you can also use "//cite"  depends how much of the url you want.